# Why does TFDMemTable->SaveToStream() throw an AV

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-11-alexandria

I am trying to convert `TFDMemTable` to a JSON String. I am trying to utilize `SaveToStream` function, but it throws an NULL Access Violation.

> Project XXX raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access
> violation at 0x545c8d4f: read of address 0x00000008'.

A reproducible code below:

```
  TFDMemTable *fd = new TFDMemTable(NULL);

  TFieldDef *Field = fd->FieldDefs->AddFieldDef();
  Field->Name = "Name";
  Field->DataType = Db::ftString;
  Field->Size = 100;

  fd->Open();
  fd->Insert();

  fd->FieldByName("Name")->AsString = "Johnny";

  fd->Post();

  TStringStream *Stream = new TStringStream();

  fd->SaveToStream(Stream, sfJSON);
```

I tried with dropping a `TFDStanStorageJSONLink` also tried creating `TStringStream` with a String.

IDE: Rad Studio 11.1. We had a similar working peice of code before upgrading from 10.1 Berlin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is fine, the problem is with the upgraded project file. If I try in a new project, it works. Ended up creating a new project file. My upgrade wows continues.